# How to profile Sitecore startup time in Azure

Tags: azure, performance-profiling

It is quite easy to profile Sitecore startup time on-premise, e.g. using JetBrains dotTrace. However, I can't find any good tools to do the same with Sitecore in Azure.

JetBrains dotTrace simply does not support Azure. The standard Azure .NET Profiler can record only 60 seconds and I guess it can't trigger a website start.

What tools or approaches can be used to get the details about code executions in Azure when Sitecore starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally tried this, but you might be able to profile the startup of your Sitecore Azure instance with these two configurations:

1. Increase the profiling session duration, configuring the `IIS_PROFILING_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` configuration setting of your App Service. The maximum value is 900 seconds.
2. Enable the App Insights .net profiler in your app service (more info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler)) and configure it with a trigger on the CPU with a low threshold (the CPU will probably spike during the Sitecore instance startup). More info on trigger setup [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-settings).

A low CPU threshold should trigger the profiling session soon enough in the startup process.